# Transform view of table using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following table

```
Date    Input   Output  Rate 
10/10/2001  10  15  0.5
10/11/2002  13  14  0.3

 1. Date    Input   Output  Rate 
 2. 10/10/2001  10  15  0.5
 3. 10/11/2002  13  14  0.3
```

I need to transform this table in the following table:

```
 1. Date    Category    Amount
 2. 10/10/2001  Input   10 
 3. 10/10/2001  Output  15
 4. 10/10/2001  Rate    0.5
 5. 10/11/2002  Input   13
 6. 10/11/2002  Output  14
 7. 10/11/2002  Rate    0.3
```

Which query should I use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What SQL have you tried?

Comment: Since this looks like measurement data, is the amount of data huge or is it just few rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Date DATE, Input DECIMAL(5, 1), [Output] DECIMAL(5, 1), Rate DECIMAL(5, 1));
INSERT @T VALUES ('20011010', 10, 15, 0.5), ('20021110', 13, 14, 0.3);

SELECT  upvt.Date, upvt.Category, upvt.Amount
FROM    @T 
        UNPIVOT
        (   Amount
            FOR Category IN ([input], [Output], [Rate])
        ) upvt;
```

However, I prefer the slightly more flexible [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with a [table valued constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Date DATE, Input DECIMAL(5, 1), [Output] DECIMAL(5, 1), Rate DECIMAL(5, 1));
INSERT @T VALUES ('20011010', 10, 15, 0.5), ('20021110', 13, 14, 0.3);

SELECT  t.Date, upvt.Category, upvt.Amount
FROM    @T AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES
            ('Input', t.Input),
            ('Output', t.[Output]),
            ('Rate', t.Rate)
        ) AS upvt (Category, Amount);
```

As it affords you more flexibility with your datatype conversions, and with renaming your columns slightly differently, e.g. it is easier to make a column like `CallStartTime` something like `Call Start`, so it is more report friendly.

e.g if your input and output columns are actually integers, you will get an error message when using `UNPIVOT`:

> The type of column "Rate" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

So you would need to use a subquery, and convert your columns there:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Date DATE, Input INT, [Output] INT, Rate DECIMAL(5, 1));
INSERT @T VALUES ('20011010', 10, 15, 0.5), ('20021110', 13, 14, 0.3);

SELECT  upvt.Date, upvt.Category, upvt.Amount
FROM    (   SELECT  Date,
                    Input = CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 1), Input),
                    [Output] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 1), [Output]),
                    Rate
            FROM    @T 
        ) AS t
        UNPIVOT
        (   Amount
            FOR Category IN ([input], [Output], [Rate])
        ) upvt;
```

And while you have to do the same conversion with CROSS APPLY, it seems like less clutter to me:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Date DATE, Input INT, [Output] INT, Rate DECIMAL(5, 1));
INSERT @T VALUES ('20011010', 10, 15, 0.5), ('20021110', 13, 14, 0.3);

SELECT  t.Date, upvt.Category, upvt.Amount
FROM    @T AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES
            ('Input', CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 1), Input)),
            ('Output', CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 1), [Output])),
            ('Rate', t.Rate)
        ) AS upvt (Category, Amount);
```

It is of course, personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a simple Standard SQL UNION ALL which is supported by every DBMS -> portable :-)

```
SELECT  Date, 'Input' AS Category, Cast(Input as DEC(5,1)) AS Amount
FROM    Tab
UNION ALL
SELECT  Date, 'Output' AS Category, Output
FROM    Tab
UNION ALL
SELECT  Date, 'Rate' AS Category, Rate
FROM    Tab
```